# Facebook Login API not returning age range

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, omniauth

I'm using the Facebook Login API with the facebook [omniauth gem](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook)

According to the Facebook [docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/v2.5#reference-public_profile) the public profile should return an age range. However, as is documented in the omnuath [doc](https://github.com/mkdynamic/omniauth-facebook) in the Auth Hash section (and as I've seen in my app) there is no age range being returned.

I'm using the `omniauth-facebook -> 1.4.0` but I don't think that matters because the docs still don't have that field being returned.

How can I access `age_range` on the `public_profile`?

Comment: You need to ask for those additional fields now, using the `fields` parameter ([example in Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Dname%2Cage_range&version=v2.5)). How to do that in Omniauth, you’ll need to go research yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ask for those additional fields now, using the fields parameter – [example in Graph API Explorer](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Dname%2Cage_range&version=v2.5).

More about this in the changelog, section “declarative fields” – https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog#v2_4_changes